# How can you suppress auto-responses to mass emails?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013

Our company has a policy that anyone who is absent for whatever reason needs to set up an auto-response message in Outlook. The text is standardized.

I sometimes need to send emails to large groups of recipients. So whenever I do this, I get flooded with auto-response messages which I then need to delete manually.

But I don't want to suppress auto-responses in general, because I find them useful when I write to just one or a small number of people.

Is there an easy way in Outlook 2013 to suppress auto-responses on a per-email level? Or maybe create a rule to delete auto-responses when the mail which triggered the response had more than a certain number of recipients?

Comment: I don't think that is possible by default since the *Rules* you can set up only work on examining email by email on certain conditions, but not like counting emails with the same subject or so.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Leun4m that there is no built-in feature to realize this. Also Outlook doesn't have a specific option to not receive Out of Office replies.

Considering that generally when you send to someone within your Exchange organization, a mail tip could display the Automatic Reply message for the person as well (Outlook 2010 or later and Exchange 2010 or later), personally I'd like to recommend using rules to delete or move all the automatic replies as they arrive in your Inbox:

[image]

Then when you write to just one or a small number of people, you can check the mail tips for the auto reply info.